# Apache Camel - Exporting data in JSON format in one (too) big line

Tags: json, apache-camel

I am exporting data (Java DTO's) into text files with JSON format using following route section at the end:

```
    JsonDataFormat jsonDataFormat = new JsonDataFormat(JsonLibrary.Gson);
    jsonDataFormat.setPrettyPrint(Boolean.TRUE);

    // ...

    .setProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME, constant(UTF))
    .marshal(jsonDataFormat) //.json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
    .convertBodyTo(String.class, UTF) // 2. change to "UTF" encoding
    .convertBodyTo(byte[].class, UTF) // 3. convert string to byte
    .to("file:/?charset=utf-8")//
```

Since there is a lot of data, the output is big.
That is not a problem. The problem is that it is all written in one long line.

To test the data I have to open those files. I like to use Notepad++, since with that editor I can format it using the "JSON Viewer" plugin.

When these files are bigger than a certain size (around 100 KB or 100 millions characters), it is not possible to open the file with Notepad++.
But not only that. The handling of the files is difficult because of that long line.

Therefore I am looking for a method to insert some "carriage return" using "pretty print". 
The code above do not work. Any idea why? Or any other way to reach that without using other libraries?

camel-version>2.14.0
gson-version>2.2.2

Comment: You can turn on pretty print mode on the json data format

Comment: in the version 2.14 ? I thought that came with version 2.16.

Comment: You could also use Jackson in a processor. I think it has support for prettyprint, if that is not supported in 2.14.

Answer (score 1):

As described in Camel JSON documentation [Camel JSON](http://camel.apache.org/json.html)
you can set dataFormat in xml:

```
<dataFormats>
    <json id="gson" prettyPrint="true" library="Gson"/>
</dataFormats>
```

and in Java DSL you can use it like:

```
.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson, true)
.convertBodyTo(String.class, UTF)
.convertBodyTo(byte[].class, UTF)
.to("file:/?charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: I tried that. It is not possible (in Version 2.14).